# phpの配列を参照してSQLでテーブルを結合したい

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

phpの配列
array('a'=>'1','b'=>2)
という配列があり
テーブルA
id | val
a  | 'aaa'
b  | 'bbb'

テーブルB
num | val
1   | '111'
2   | '222'
の２つのテーブルをsqlで下記のように結び付けたいです。
select 結果
id | val | num | val
a  | 'aaa'| 1   | '111'
b  | 'bbb'| 2   | '222'

何かいい方法はあるでしょうか。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

下記のようにすれば可能です。
性能的に結合条件にINDEX指定することをお勧めします。
※バージョンによってはできないかも知れません。

```
SELECT
        *
    FROM
        (
        VALUES
            ('a',1)　　　　← ここを配列の要素をまわして、作成
            ,('b',2) 
        ) AS phpData (phpid, phpval)  ← テーブル名（カラム１．．．）
            LEFT JOIN テーブルA
                ON テーブルA.id = phpData.phpid
            LEFT JOIN テーブルB
                ON テーブルB.val = phpData.phpval;
```

Comment: 無事に作成できました、ありがとうございます！